# Problemas com WampServer

Tags: wamp

Estou aprendendo a mexer com o `WampServer` ainda, mas já tenho um impasse.
No meu notebook esta instalado o `WampServer` e uma pagina web em construção.

Para testar, uso o browser do notebook e do meu celular. No entanto, quando escrevo no computador,por exemplo, **localhost/projeto/index.php** o código funciona perfeitamente, mas no celular da erro. Não encontra o endereço digitado, e ambos estão na mesma rede.

Se digitar na url do notebook,por exemplo, **192.168.10.100/projeto/index.php** também abre mas certas partes do código não funcionam, como evento de abrir a camera do notebook. No celular o comportamento é idêntico, também não abre a camera.

Alguém sabe me explicar por que isso ocorre e se tem alguma forma de que eu possa acessar do mesmo modo nos 2 dispositivos sem esses erros?

Comment: No celular, já tentou acessar pelo endereço IP do servidor? Provavelmente, 192.168.10.100/projeto/index.php

Comment: Você deve estar utilizando referências absolutas aos recursos, tais como links ou imagens. Você deve utilizar referências relativas. Exemplo de link absoluto: `<a href="http://localhost/projeto/index.php">Link</a>` Exemplo de link relativo: `<a href="projeto/index.php">Link</a>` ou ainda `<a href="index.php">Link</a>`
dependendo de onde você está o referenciando. Recomendaria verificar o que está saindo no código fonte gerado, ou ainda checar a aba "Network" do "Developer Tools" no Chrome a partir de outro computador, para verificar para onde os recursos que não estão abrindo estão apontando.

Comment: Acredito que não deva ser problema do Wamp não, mas de permissão de acesso à câmera a partir de um ip diferente do localhost. Espero que alguém responda a sua pergunta pq agora eu fiquei curioso... :)